# Can't set date via shell

Tags: adb, root-access, shell, file-permissions

I've tried

```
date -u 1407697765
```

output:

```
time 1407697765 -> 1407697765.0
settimeofday failed Bad file number
```

and

```
busybox date -s @1407697765
```

output:

```
date: can't set date: Operation not permitted
```

I don't feel that I'm doing everything right (especially when `date -u`) but it looks like I have no permission... I'm trying it through adb shell

Why do I get these errors and how to set date through shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `root` user can set the date. If your phone is already rooted, just type `su`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get into a root shell, then the command you want to run.

If your phone is not already rooted, you'll need to get root access first. See [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: I thought that adb shell uses root by default ><

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me (once you have root permissions):

```
adb shell settings put global auto_time 0 && adb shell date 010219302018.00 set && adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET
```

`auto_time` -> This is to switch off automatic syncing of time.

To reset the time back to syncing with the network, do:

```
adb shell settings put global auto_time 1 && adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue the following commands:

```
adb shell date -s YYYYMMDD.HHmmss
```

or

```
$ adb shell 
$ adb root
# su 
# date -s YYYYMMDD.HHmmss
```