# Setting Date on Android device works from settings menu but requires root access via ADB (which I do not have)

Tags: root-access, date-and-time, headset

If not set to automatic, the date and time of the Pico G2 4K headset is never correct. I'm attempting to set it manually via the command line like this:

```
adb shell "toybox date 110309162023.14"
```

and finding that root access is required, however when I enter the developer settings menu in the headset, I can change the date and time with no issue. Is there something I'm missing or a different command I should be trying?

I've tried searching the Pico XR documentation, as well as issuing similar commands like `adb shell toolbox date <datestring>` and `adb shell date <datestring>` as well as searching Stack Overflow for similar questions. So far nothing has worked.

Thanks in advance for any guidance with this!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Possible duplicate: [Can't set date via shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/79243/44325)

Comment: Welcome Dave! Does the possible duplicate that Andrew provided answer your question?  It appears that root is required.  It's certainly not the desired answer, but appears to be the correct answer.  It appears you are doing everything correctly, but the task unfortunately requires root.